# Memory Error with numpy on several large arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I am trying to carry out the following calculations on a series of large arrays but I keep getting the error:

```
MemoryError
```

In total there are 9 grain_size arrays 2745 by 2654 (Note: I could use just a single float here instead of an array as it is an array of the same number in every cell and this doesn't change), 9 g_pro arrays 2745 by 2654 and the 9 arrays I create below.

So I guess my questions would be is there a way to work around this issue?

```
# Create empty arrays to store the information
Fs1 = np.zeros_like(g_pro_1, dtype = float)
Fs2 = np.zeros_like(g_pro_1, dtype = float)
Fs3 = np.zeros_like(g_pro_1, dtype = float)
Fs4 = np.zeros_like(g_pro_1, dtype = float)
Fs5 = np.zeros_like(g_pro_1, dtype = float)
Fs6 = np.zeros_like(g_pro_1, dtype = float)
Fs7 = np.zeros_like(g_pro_1, dtype = float)
Fs8 = np.zeros_like(g_pro_1, dtype = float)
Fs9 = np.zeros_like(g_pro_1, dtype = float)

# Check where the condition is true
np.putmask(Fs1, np.logical_and(grain_size_1_array > 0.0000625, grain_size_1_array <= 0.002), g_pro_1)
np.putmask(Fs2, np.logical_and(grain_size_2_array > 0.0000625, grain_size_2_array <= 0.002), g_pro_2)
np.putmask(Fs3, np.logical_and(grain_size_3_array > 0.0000625, grain_size_3_array <= 0.002), g_pro_3)
np.putmask(Fs4, np.logical_and(grain_size_4_array > 0.0000625, grain_size_4_array <= 0.002), g_pro_4)
np.putmask(Fs5, np.logical_and(grain_size_5_array > 0.0000625, grain_size_5_array <= 0.002), g_pro_5)
np.putmask(Fs6, np.logical_and(grain_size_6_array > 0.0000625, grain_size_6_array <= 0.002), g_pro_6)
np.putmask(Fs7, np.logical_and(grain_size_7_array > 0.0000625, grain_size_7_array <= 0.002), g_pro_7)
np.putmask(Fs8, np.logical_and(grain_size_8_array > 0.0000625, grain_size_8_array <= 0.002), g_pro_8)
np.putmask(Fs9, np.logical_and(grain_size_9_array > 0.0000625, grain_size_9_array <= 0.002), g_pro_9)

Fs = Fs1 + Fs2 + Fs3 + Fs4 + Fs5 + Fs6 + Fs7 + Fs8 + Fs9
Fs[self.discharge == -9999] = -9999
```

The code that worked for me now is:

```
Fs = np.zeros_like(g_pro_1, dtype = float)

    grain_array_list = [self.grain_size_1, self.grain_size_2, self.grain_size_3,    self.grain_size_4, self.grain_size_5, self.grain_size_6, self.grain_size_7, self.grain_size_8, self.grain_size_9]
    proportions_list = [g_pro_1, g_pro_2, g_pro_3, g_pro_4, g_pro_5, g_pro_6, g_pro_7, g_pro_8, g_pro_9]

    for proportion, grain in izip(proportions_list, grain_array_list):  
        if grain > 0.0000625 and grain <= 0.002:
            print grain
            Fs = Fs + proportion

    Fs[self.discharge == -9999] = -9999
```

Comment: Post the complete traceback.

Comment: just rerunning now laptop crashed will post in a few minutes

Comment: Why would you use `putmask` with a mask that's always all true or all false?

Comment: Perhaps I am not using the correct method to get the desired result. I effectively want to add the g_pro arrays together dependent on the grainsizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you see lines of code that only differ by a single character, you should be using a loop. In your case, you are holding data that you are not using in memory. Your workflow is basically

- get a `grain_size_array`
- apply a mask to `grain_size_array`
- add the mask to a placeholder (`Fs`)
- dispose of the mask and `grain_size_array`

In terms of code, you need something like:

```
g_pro_1 = load() # however you get that
Fs = np.zeros_like(g_pro_1, dtype = float)
Fs_tmp = np.zeros_like(g_pro_1, dtype = float)
for i in range(10):
    g_pro = load() # whatever
    grain_size_array = load() # whatever
    np.putmask(Fs_tmp, np.logical_and(grain_size_array > 0.0000625, grain_size_array <= 0.002), g_pro_1)
    Fs += Fs_tmp
```

Comment: Ok this makes sense to me as I have said in the comment below memory usage etc is still new to me. I have never used load before so I will have a look into that now. Thanks

Comment: `Load` is just a word I used to indicate you should get the data somehow. Your question doesn't specify where `g_pro_1` comes from, so I assumed you load that from a file or something (hence the word load).

Comment: Hi yeh my bad I worked that out haha - I have posted my final code that fixed the memory issue above!

Answer (score 1):

Your example requires `9*2745*2654*sizeof(float)` Bytes, i.e. 500 MiB, to store the `grain_size` arrays and again as much to store the `g_pro` arrays. To run the `logical_and` functions, the parameter arrays with the results of the comparisons must be stored, adding another 100 Mib. Maybe you really simply run out of memory eventually?

You could either try

- to increase the physical or swap memory available on your system, or
- to create and process the `Fs<n>` arrays one after another rather than having each of them in memory at the same time

Comment: As someone who is still new to programing at what point does is the files "dumped" from the memory? If I am using classes and functions?

Comment: Once you either use `del foo` to explicitly delete the variable `foo`, assign another value to it, i.e. `foo = None`, or it leaves scope, it is marked for deletion by the Garbage Collector. See p.e. [here](http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection) for details.